# Update Tour to include Game Rec/Shopping in off-topic section

Tags: discussion, status-completed

As the title says the [Tour](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tour) currently does not include the 'Game Rec/Shopping' reason to not ask a question. It includes the other explicit categories of off-topic questions listed on the [On-Topic](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page, and I think it should be updated to include this one too.

Comment: I +1 this.  Other stack exchange sites allow this. Because this site does not, it should be explicit, especially when dealing with the love of board games.  Sometimes it can be hard to find a game that you are looking for, making this seem like a good place to go to ask questions. If not, then the tour should be updated to explicitly state recommendations are off topic.

Comment: I would like to point out that most Stack Exchange sites do not actually allow recommendation questions. In fact, the only site I know of that does allow them is the Software Recommendations site.

Comment: Hardware Recommendations exists too. But in both cases, they have fairly high standards about asking questions, that it's taken a lot of time and effort to work out, and plenty of too-fuzzy questions get closed. If we were to follow their example, folks probably still wouldn't be all that happy.

Comment: RPG Stack Exchange allows various kinds of recommendations, but recently ruled out product recommendations. The main reason was: a lot of established users were taking umbrage with the rules, so we couldn't have nice things; otherwise the rules largely worked OK. (The primary rule people took issue was "say or demonstrate you've used that product for what you're recommending it for" which is rather important.)

Comment: @doppelgreener Just to clarify, are you talking about recommendations or requests for recommendations? It sounds like you are talking about the former, while this post is concerned with the latter.

Comment: @Rainbolt We have a standard form of question where someone asks "how do I realise this character concept in this game?" or "I'm almost done with this character concept, how do I do this last 5%?" and we answer how.

Comment: That's not really "recommendation" questions, as the term applies here. We specifically ban recommendations for games, expansions, and similar. I think that what you're describing would fall into the category that we just call "subjective".